# Make Indent for <li>

Tags: css, html-lists

I've tried putting 10px of padding in but no success. You can see an example of it [lower down on this page](http://www.glamourunderground.com/309/organic-networking-the-5-point-guide/).

```
  #menu li {
        float: left;
        margin: 0px 0 0px 0;
        padding: 0 0 0 10px;
        }
```

Thanks to everyone who answers!
Tara

Comment: i am voting to close because you dont have an id called menu anywhere in that page.

Comment: @Naveen - Why is that a reason to vote to close?

Comment: @Naveen Your right, this is the wrong attribute, I should be targeting just li {}

Comment: @ My Head Hurts: because the OP is asking to search on a web page which doesn't even have that attribute. who ever ask should take sometime and be clear with their question, IMHO. tara, no offense :)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how your page is made, but adding a margin-left of 200px on the ul element works. (Assuming we are talking about the ul under "When you’re Asking for Advice")

Comment: I tired this just now, 'ul {
 float: left;
 margin: 0px 0 0px 0;
 padding: 0 0 0 10px;
 }' but it made the bullet points stick 10px from the far left side, not the grey box.

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap your content in a `div` with a new formatting context after `#sidebox2000`.